# How to use apostrophe ' with babel french loaded?

Tags: punctuation, babel, typography

The french apostrophe is the following ’, when babel french is loaded it automatically turns typed apostrophes ' into ’.

How to preserve the apostrophe ' in some cases (quote for example) but not in all the document ?

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}

\begin{document}
l'exemple d'une apostrophe (it's fine here)\\
quote: 'text of the quote' (it's not,' should be preserved)
\end{document}
```

Comment: That said, you should use either *guillemets*,  or use `\emph`. Single quotes are british.

Comment: Are you calling “apostrophe” the “straight quote”?

Comment: @egreg i meant by quote citation and not quote the punctuation symbol (“ ”) sorry for confusion. yes exactly the seconde line in the example should be a straight single quote (') instead of a closing single quote (’)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The fact you're using `babel-french` has nothing to do with the problem.

Straight quotes are very rarely used in typography, so when you type the `'` character, you get a curly glyph that serves both as a closing quote and as apostrophe.

If you want a straight quote, you can use the glyph provided by `textcomp`.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % mandatory for French
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage{textcomp}

\begin{document}

l'exemple d'une apostrophe

quote: \textquotesingle text of the quote\textquotesingle

\end{document}
```

[image]